# On Google login redirect to https://myaccount.google.com/ when multiple Google account is logged in at the same time in browser - Laravel

Tags: laravel, google-signin

I  am tired with Google login, when single Gmail account logged in browser everything fine, but when two or more Gmail account logged in browser then login successfully but redirect in the google account setting (url:https://myaccount.google.com), here is my controller code. I want to redirect to back page.

```
public function redirect()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
    }


    public function callback()
    {
            $googleUser = Socialite::driver('google')->user();
            $existUser = User::where('email',$googleUser->email)->first();


            if($existUser) {
                Auth::loginUsingId($existUser->id);
            }
            else {
                $user = new User;
                $user->first_name = $googleUser->name;
                $user->email = $googleUser->email;
                $user->google_id = $googleUser->id;
                $user->password = bcrypt(rand(1,10));
                $user->save();
                Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);
            }
                return back();
        }
```

[Redirect to this page, I want to redirect back page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVUM3.png)

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of `return back();` since your server is redirecting back to Google through the HTTP Referer header. This header is unreliable, please do not use it.

Instead, before login with google, save the current URL in the user session and after the login callback, redirect to that URL. In this way, you will be able to bring the user back to the original page.